# any issue with April 2019 CU / May 2019 CU for sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

Just wanted to know if any issue or regression with with April 2019 CU / May 2019 CU for SharePoint 2013 ?

Has anyone experience nay

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with April 2019 CU and May 2019 CU for sharepoint 2013 in the official documents.

Then we recommend that you test those hotfixes before you deploy them in a production environment.

More references:

[April 9, 2019, cumulative update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB4464514).](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464514/april-9-2019-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013-k)

[May 14, 2019, cumulative update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB4464563).](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464563/may-14-2019-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013-kb)

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue that we encountered .

The word automation service application stopped working after we applied this CU .

Tried this for both the SharePoint 2013 as well as SharePoint 2016 farms.

The issue is that the CU revokes the permission of the service account running the application pool of the Word automation service application .

So after you have patched your environment make sure you have given the permission back again and try once if your word automation service application is able to convert documents to pdf's.

I will keep you updated on more issues as I keep finding them .

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, just to understand clearly .. does the "word automation service" problem occurs in both the CU or you are referring to specific one ?

Comment: We encountered this issue for April 2019 CU only for both SP 2013 and SP2016 environments

Answer (score 0):

Just to sharing my experience.

I installed April 2019 updates on SharePoint 2013.

There is no issue with the CU.

Everything is fine after upgrade.